# Как получить список файлов?

Tags: python

есть файлы в директории:

```
$ ls date/
passport_blacklist_01032021.xlsx  passport_blacklist_03032021.xlsx  terminals_02032021.xlsx  transactions_01032021.txt  transactions_03032021.txt
passport_blacklist_02032021.xlsx  terminals_01032021.xlsx           terminals_03032021.xlsx  transactions_02032021.txt
```

как в питоне создать такой список, чтобы можно было отсортировать так: в первом списке были файлы:

```
passport_blacklist_01032021.xlsx
terminals_01032021.xlsx
transactions_01032021.txt
```

а во втором списке файлы:

```
terminals_02032021.xlsx
transactions_02032021.txt
passport_blacklist_02032021.xlsx
```

а в третьем списке файлы:

```
passport_blacklist_03032021.xlsx
terminals_03032021.xlsx
transactions_03032021.txt
```

я пытаюсь начать так, но почему то мне пустые списки выдает программа

```
search_dir = os.getcwd()
suffixes=["01032021", "02032021", "03032021"]
for suffix in suffixes:
        #listfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(search_dir) if f.endswith(suffix)]
        for f in os.listdir(search_dir)
                print(f)
```

Comment: 1. по какому принципу идет разделение на списки? 2. Ни один из файлов у вас не заканчивается ни на какой суффикс и указанных. Они заканчиваются на ``xlsx`` или ``txt``

Comment: @Эникейщик суффикс имееются ввиду по названию даты

Comment: похоже, вы не совсем поняли, что я имел в виду :)

Answer (score 0):

Например, `passport_blacklist_01032021.xlsx` заканчивается не на `01032021`, а на `xlsx`.

Нужно заменить `f.endswith(suffix)` на `suffix in f`

```
listfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(search_dir) if suffix in f]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: хехе, перепутал с другим. Исправил, попробуйте сейчас